# Output not showing in R Markdown PDF

Tags: r, markdown

I'm new to coding and for one of my assignments I have to use R Markdown and convert it to a PDF WITH my output. So I downloaded latex and chunked (I think is the right term) my code, but when I try to knit to a pdf in Markdown, my code shows up, but the output does not?

Comment: please show an example of your code (I'm particularly interested in the beginning of the chunk, eg ``` {r ...} )

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing your code (see [mcve]), but I'd check the [chunk options](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/rmarkdown-reference.pdf) in your code to make sure you haven't suppressed results using `{r results = 'hide'}` or something